# System call interrupted by a signal still has to be completed

Tags: c++, c, unix, interrupt, eintr

A lot of system calls like `close( fd )` Can be interrupted by a signal. In this case usually `-1` is returned and `errno` is set `EINTR`.

The question is what is the right thing to do? Say, I still want this `fd` to be closed.

What I can come up with is:

```
while( close( fd ) == -1 )
  if( errno != EINTR ) {
    ReportError();
    break;
  }
```

Can anybody suggest a better/more elegant/standard way to handle this situation?

UPDATE:
As noticed by mux, SA_`RESTART` flag can be used when installing the signal handler.
Can somebody tell me which functions are guaranteed to be restartable on all `POSIX` systems(not only `Linux`)?

Comment: Although in general this might be the correct approach, for `close()` in particular, at least on Linux, it is **not** recommended. Please read here: https://lkml.org/lkml/2002/7/17/165

Comment: I see. But I don't think it's guaranteed that the same happens on all UNIX systems. I need a portable solution.

Comment: May be you can comment on the updated question? Would be great.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Some system calls are restartable, which means the kernel will restart the call if interrupted, if the `SA_RESTART` flag is used when installing the signal handler, the [signal(7)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man7/signal.7.html) man page says:

> If a blocked call to one of the following interfaces is interrupted
>   by a signal handler, **then the call will be automatically  restarted 
>   after  the  signal
>          handler returns if the SA_RESTART flag was used**; otherwise the call will fail with the error EINTR:

It doesn't mention if `close()` is restartable, but these are:

> read(2), readv(2), write(2), writev(2), ioctl(2), open(2),wait(2),
>   wait3(2), wait4(2), waitid(2), and waitpid,accept(2), connect(2),
>   recv(2), recvfrom(2), recvmsg(2), send(2), sendto(2), and sendmsg(2)
>   flock(2) and fcntl(2) mq_receive(3), mq_timedreceive(3), mq_send(3),
>   and mq_timedsend(3) sem_wait(3) and sem_timedwait(3) futex(2)

*Note that those details, specifically the list of non-restartable calls, are Linux-specific*

I posted a relevant question about which system calls are restartable and if it's specified by POSIX somewhere, it is specified by POSIX but it's optional, so you should check the list of non-restartable calls for your OS, if it's not there it should be restartable. This is my question:
[How to know if a Linux system call is restartable or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13357019/how-to-know-if-a-linux-system-call-is-restartable-or-not/13357338#13357338)

Update: Close is a special case it's not restartable and should not be retried in Linux, see this answer for more details:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/14431867/1157444

Comment: You got this from `man signal(7)` on a Linux system? In case yes: this list is valid for Linux only. On the same man page it is stated: "*The details vary across Unix systems*"

Comment: OK, can you point me to a list of functions guaranteed to be restartable by POSIX or something?

Comment: close() must not be retried on every sane UNIX (HP-UX is the only common exception). Can we fix this answer, for the record?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're after shorter code, you can try something like:

```
while (((rc = close (fd)) == -1) && (errno == EINTR));
if (rc == -1)
    complainBitterly (errno);
```

Assuming you're after more *readable* code in addition to shorter, just create a function:

```
int closeWithRetry (int fd);
```

and place your readable code in there. Then it doesn't really matter how long it is, it's still a one-liner where you call it, but you can make the function body itself very readable:

```
int closeWithRetry (int fd) {
    // Initial close attempt.

    int rc = close (fd);

    // As long as you failed with EINTR, keep trying.
    // Possibly with a limit (count or time-based).

    while ((rc == -1) && (errno == EINTR))
        rc = close (fd);

    // Once either success or non-retry failure, return error code.

    return rc;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For the record: On essentially every UNIX, `close()` *must not be retried* if it returns EINTR. **DO NOT** put an EINTR retry-loop in place for close like you would for `waitpid()` or `read()`. See this page for more details: http://austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=529 On linux, Solaris, BSD and others, retrying `close()` is incorrect. HP-UX is the only common(!) system I could find that requires this.

EINTR means something very different for `read()` and `select()` and `waitpid()` and so on than it does for `close()`. For most calls, you retry on EINTR because you asked for something to be done which blocks, and if you were interrupted that means it didn't happen, so you try again. For `close()`, the action you requested was for an entry to be removed from the fd table, which is instantaneous, without error, and will always happen no matter what `close()` returns.[*] The only reason `close()` blocks is that sometimes, for special semantics (like TCP linger), it can wait until I/O is done before returning. If close returns EINTR, that means that you asked it to wait but it couldn't. However, *the fd was still closed*; you just lost your chance to wait on it.

Conclusion: unless you know you can't receive signals, using `close()` for waiting is a very stupid thing to do. Use an application-level ACK (TCP) or an fsync (file I/O) to make sure any writes were completed before closing the fd.

[*] There is a caveat: if another thread of the process is inside a blocking syscall on the same fd, well, ... it depends.