# How to close a file?

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, signals, posix

I felt at peace with Posix after many years of experience.

Then I read [this](https://lkml.org/lkml/2002/7/17/165) message from Linus Torvalds, circa 2002:

> > ```
> > int ret;
> > do {
> >     ret = close(fd);
> > } while(ret == -1 && errno != EBADF);
> > ```
>
> NO.
>
> The above is
>
> > (a) not portable
> >
> > (b) not current practice
>
> The "not portable" part comes from the fact that (as somebody pointed
>   out), a threaded environment in which the kernel *does* close the FD
>   on errors, the FD may have been validly re-used (by the kernel) for
>   some other thread, and closing the FD a second time is a BUG.

Not only is looping until `EBADF` unportable, but any loop is, due to a race condition that I probably would have noticed if I hadn't "made peace" by taking such things for granted.

However, in the GCC C++ standard library implementation, `basic_file_stdio.cc`, we have

```
    do
      __err = fclose(_M_cfile);
    while (__err && errno == EINTR);
```

The primary target for this library is Linux, but it seems not to be heeding Linus.

As far as I've come to understand, `EINTR` happens only after a system call *blocks*, which implies that the kernel received the request to free the descriptor before commencing whatever work got interrupted. So there's no need to loop. Indeed, the `SA_RESTART` signal behavior does not apply to `close` and generate such a loop by default, precisely because it is unsafe.

This is a standard library bug then, right? On every file ever closed by a C++ application.

**EDIT:** To avoid causing too much alarm before some guru comes along with an answer, I should note that [`close`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/close.html) only seems to be allowed to block under specific circumstances, perhaps none of which ever apply to regular files. I'm not clear on all the details, but you should not see `EINTR` from `close` without opting into something by `fcntl` or `setsockopt`. Nevertheless the possibility makes generic library code more dangerous.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/13356497/153285 where I got the link.

Comment: I think the EINTR would come from the implicit fflush, in which case `close` would not be called. To be cautious, one should call fflush explicitly. But, given your link, perhaps you meant `close` and not `fclose`?

Comment: @JimBalter Ah, good point. And `fclose` doesn't handle that internally because it's *pretending* to be a system call. I think that just might be the answer… but we still need to verify that this loop *cannot* result in two files being closed.

Comment: @JimBalter Yes, my question is about `close` specifically, not stdio or iostreams, which are just a canonical use-case and a reliable example to work from.

Comment: Well, since fclose calls close which can produce an EINTR, then two files can be closed, assuming the answer by Nicholas Wilson at that link is correct.

Comment: @JimBalter So. It seems there's no way to reliably close exactly one file, and not zero or two, using the C or C++ standard libraries on any platform including Linux, or using Posix `close` without digging into platform-specific docs. That's sort of bad.

Comment: Note that looping on EBADF is normally meaningless. It means the file descriptor you pass into it is not valid. And it never will be valid within such a loop - unless you intend for another thread to open it up in the mean time (which would be a rather insane thing to intentionally do, and an easy thing to accidentally do)

Comment: @nos No, it's not meaningless ... close will result in EBADF if fd is already closed, which *may or may not* have happened on the previous iteration. According to Nominal Animal's answer, it always will have been closed in Linux and FreeBSD, and probably in OpenBSD and Mac OS X, but POSIX doesn't mandate it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With respect to POSIX, [R..](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13357019/how-to-know-if-a-linux-system-call-is-restartable-or-not/14431867#14431867)'s [answer to a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13357019/how-to-know-if-a-linux-system-call-is-restartable-or-not/14431867#14431867) is very clear and concise: `close()` is a non-restartable special case, and no loop should be used.

This was surprising to me, so I decided to describe my findings, followed by my conclusions and chosen solution at end.

This is not really an answer. Consider this more like the opinion of a fellow programmer, including the reasoning behind that opinion.

---

[POSIX.1-2001](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/functions/close.html) and [POSIX.1-2008](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/close.html) describe three possible errno values that may occur: `EBADF`, `EINTR`, and `EIO`. The descriptor state after `EINTR` and `EIO` is *"unspecified"*, which means it may or may not have been closed. `EBADF` indicates `fd` is not a valid descriptor. In other words, POSIX.1 clearly recommends using

```
    if (close(fd) == -1) {
        /* An error occurred, see 'errno'. */
    }
```

without any retry looping to close file descriptors.

(Even the Austin Group [defect #519](http://austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=529#c1200) R.. mentioned, does not help with recovering from `close()` errors: it leaves it unspecified whether any I/O is possible after an `EINTR` error, even if the descriptor itself is left open.)

---

For Linux, the `close()` syscall is defined in [fs/open.c](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/fs/open.c), with `__do_close()` in [fs/file.c](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/fs/file.c) managing the descriptor table locking, and `filp_close()` back in [fs/open.c](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/fs/open.c) taking care of the details.

In summary, the descriptor entry is removed from the table unconditionally *first*, followed by filesystem-specific flushing (`f_op->flush()`), followed by notification (dnotify/fsnotify hook), and finally by removing any record or file locks. (Most local filesystems like ext2, ext3, ext4, xfs, bfs, tmpfs, and so on, do not have `->flush()`, so given a valid descriptor, `close()` cannot fail. Only ecryptfs, exofs, fuse, cifs, and nfs have `->flush()` handlers in Linux-3.13.6, as far as I can tell.)

This does mean that in Linux, if a write error occurs in the filesystem-specific `->flush()` handler during `close()`, *there is no way to retry*; the file descriptor is always closed, just like Torvalds said.

The FreeBSD [`close()`](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=close&sektion=2) man page describes the exact same behaviour.

Neither the [OpenBSD](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=close&sektion=2) nor the [Mac OS X](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man2/close.2.html) `close()` man pages describe whether the descriptor is closed in case of errors, but I believe they share the FreeBSD behaviour.

---

It seems clear to me that no loop is necessary or required to close a file descriptor safely. However, `close()` may still return an error.

`errno == EBADF` indicates the file descriptor was already closed. If my code encounters this unexpectedly, to me it indicates there is a significant fault in the code logic, and the process should gracefully exit; I'd rather my processes die than produce garbage.

Any other `errno` values indicate an error in finalizing the file state. In Linux, it is definitely an error related to flushing any remaining data to the actual storage. In particular, I can imagine `ENOMEM` in case there is no room to buffer the data, `EIO` if the data could not be sent or written to the actual device or media, `EPIPE` if connection to the storage was lost, `ENOSPC` if the storage is already full with no reservation to the unflushed data, and so on. If the file is a log file, I'd have the process report the failure and exit gracefully. If the file contents are still available in memory, I would remove (unlink) the entire file, and retry. Otherwise I'd report the failure to the user.

(Remember that in Linux and FreeBSD, you do not "leak" file descriptors in the error case; they are guaranteed to be closed even if an error occurs. I am assuming all other operating systems I might use behave the same way.)

The helper function I'll use from now on will be something like

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>

/**
 * closefd - close file descriptor and return error (errno) code
 *
 * @descriptor: file descriptor to close
 *
 * Actual errno will stay unmodified.
*/
static int closefd(const int descriptor)
{
    int saved_errno, result;

    if (descriptor == -1)
        return EBADF;

    saved_errno = errno;

    result = close(descriptor);
    if (result == -1)
        result = errno;

    errno = saved_errno;
    return result;
}
```

I know the above is safe on Linux and FreeBSD, and I assume it is safe on all other POSIX-y systems. If I encounter one that is not, I can simply replace the above with a custom version, wrapping it in a suitable `#ifdef` for that OS. The reason this maintains `errno` unchanged is just a quirk of my coding style; it makes short-circuiting error paths shorter (less repeated code).

If I am closing a file that contains important user information, I will do a [`fsync()` or `fdatasync()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fdatasync.2.html) on it prior to closing. This ensures the data hits the storage, but also causes a delay compared to normal operation; therefore I won't do it for ordinary data files.

Unless I will be [`unlink()`ing](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/unlink.2.html) the closed file, I will check `closefd()` return value, and act accordingly. If I can easily retry, I will, but at most once or twice. For log files and generated/streamed files, I only warn the user.

I want to remind anyone reading this far that *we cannot make anything completely reliable*; it is just not possible. What we can do, and in my opinion should do, is to *detect* when an error occurs, as reliably as we can. If we can easily and with neglible resource use retry, we should. In all cases, we should make sure the notification (about the error) is propagated to the actual human user. Let the human worry about whether some other action, possibly complex, needs to be done before the operation is retried. After all, a lot of tools are used only as a part of a larger task, and the best course of action usually depends on that larger task.

Comment: The intro and disclaimer alone deserve a +1 :) . The take-home lessons for me so far are: 1) Avoid bare fd's and be specific about what is being closed, such as to anticipate the particular surprising semantics. 2) Always test against NFS failure. Sysadmins need the reliability but shoot themselves in the foot by using this. Perhaps for optimal reliability, management of log files etc should detect NFS filesystem and transparently generate a local mirror.